# Sharepoint 2007 Newbie question - webpage markup

Tags: sharepoint-2007, standards

A web developer created our new intranet in Sharepoint 2007, none of the pages have metadata titles or descriptions (or any metadata tags) also the page has no semantic structure, divs are used instead of H1, H2, H3 etc.

He said this was a quickie out of the box creation but i'm really concerned about the quality of the page structure and the impact this will have on the effectiveness of the internal search engine.

Does a Sharepoint 2007 website come out of the box in this condition and am I right or wrong to be concerned about this?

Any advice would be appreciated as I would not accept the build of an external site like but he said "sharepoint is just like this" and I have no idea.

Many thanks
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the default master page. Add your meta tags there if the site is going to have same meta keywords and descriptions. If you want to customize the meta tags for each and every page then you will have to find the contentplaceholder ID  that will hold the head section of the page and put all your meta tags there in each and every page.